# Regex Evaluation

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm working with a PowerShell script for which I need to evaluate whether a string contains all of three specific substrings.  I don't have foreknowledge of what characters (or the length) may be in between the sub-strings I'm trying to match on.  I've tried working with non-capturing groups, but I can't get it to match 'anything' in between the strings, and to still require that all three strings exist, I don't know the right operators to use between the non-capturing groups, or whether I need to use the tempered greedy token (or how to implement that).

Here's an example string that I would want to 'match' the elements below on:
`file://ringostar.delta.campisi.com/All%20Files/RAPTOR/Deployment/All/Chaps/Chaps.application#Chaps.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abb52476a21d22b21a, processorArchitecture=x86`

Match Conditions (all three must be true):

1. Starts with: `file://`
2. Has somewhere following #1 above (but as you can see not directly adjacent): `.delta.campisi.com/`
3. Has this somewhere following #2 above (again not adjacent): `Chaps.application#Chaps.application`

This is where I'm at (which obviously doesn't work):

`^file:\/\/(?:\.delta\.campisi\.com)(?:Chaps\.application\#Chaps\.application)`

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply join your three match conditions with `.*?`, i.e., any character between zero and an unlimited number of times, as few as possible (lazy matching).

**Regex:**

```txt
^file:\/\/.*?\.delta\.campisi\.com\/.*?Chaps\.application#Chaps\.application
```

**Demo:**
https://regex101.com/r/muBuEd/1

Comment: That's perfect!  Thanks for helping the regex noob!